# Disabling all clicks and keyboard input until all code is finished running

Tags: javascript

I have several animations that show and hide elements, and if the user clicks too quickly several animations will play at the same time which creates bizarre glitches.

Right now I'm using a global is_freeze_input variable to prevent certain buttons from being pressed while animations are playing, but I have so many functions which each toggle this variable, so clicking rapidly can sometimes bypass this method of preventing input since the asynchronous nature of JavaScript means I never know when one function is freezing the input or another is unfreezing it.

I thought the cleanest solution would be to disable all input while any animations are playing. Is there a way to do that without manually toggling a variable at the beginning and end of the function?

If I use an event listener to check for all key presses and clicks, can I ignore the input entirely if any part of my code is still processing?

Edit: I have a solution that almost works using the transitionend event listener trigger. This works to disable clicks too soon, but I'm unable to get keypresses to resume after the first time the function is called.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const handleInput = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', checkKeyDown)
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', checkKeyUp)
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleInput)
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', handleInput)
    document.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
        console.log('handleClick transition end')
        document.addEventListener('keydown', checkKeyDown)
        document.addEventListener('keyup', checkKeyUp)
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleInput)
        document.addEventListener('keyup', handleInput)
    }, { once: true })
}
    document.addEventListener('keydown', checkKeyDown)
    document.addEventListener('keyup', checkKeyUp)
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleInput)
    document.addEventListener('keyup', handleInput)
```

Comment: Instead of having `is_freeze_input` be a bool, make it a number that starts at zero, is incremented when an animation starts, and is decremented with one ends. If it's zero, no animations are happening.

Comment: That's brilliant, just tried it and it's working well so far. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

**To disable the keyboard inputs:**

```
document.onkeydown = () => false
```

**To enable them back again:**

```
document.onkeydown = () => true
```

**To disable clicks:**

```
document.onclick = () => false
```

**To enable them back again:**

```
document.onclick = () => true
```

Edit:
To implement this in your project, I would suggest you do something like this:
**Create a function to disable all at the same time**

```
function disableAll() {
    document.onkeydown = () => false;
    document.onclick = () => false;
}
```

**Create a function to enable all at the same time**

```
function enableAll() {
    document.onkeydown = () => true;
    document.onclick = () => true;
}
```

And then, as bjb568 suggested, you could use a variable:

> that starts at zero, is incremented when an animation starts, and is decremented with one ends.

So that when it is cero, no animations are running. You could check after every animation end, if without that animation, the variable is cero, and if it is, you could call `enableAll()`, and you could call  `disableAll()` at the start of each animation.

Well, I hope I made myself clear, and I wish you luck with your project, Happy Coding!

Comment: I like how clean your method is, but that's not entirely what I'm trying to do. I need to somehow check if any of my functions are not yet complete. If you image all of the functions in your code had a bool that was true when it started and false when it ended, I need to disable keyboard and click input unless all of the bools are false. Ideally without actually creating those bools in all of my functions.

Comment: I updated my original post with the solution I'm working on, but it doesn't quite work. Not sure if you have any thoughts?